# How to get PID of process by specifying process name and check null or PID exist?

Tags: linux, shell, cron, redhat

How to check process id exist or not for specify process name in linux ?
I'm new script , so just adding my logic here.

```
if pgrep -f test-qa > null then
echo "Nothing"
else mail user@domain.com
fi
```

and going to setup in crontab, like

```
15 * * * * /path1/folder/test-util.sh
```

So i will get email, if server down in production. Please help me in the linux script.

Answer (score 1):

You can get pid of the process with `pidof` command, here is an example:

```
PIDS=`pidof rsync`

if [ -z "$PIDS" ]; then
    echo "No process alive... Starting an instance."
    rsync --partial --progress -avvz -e $SSH $RHOST:$RPATH $LPATH 2>&1 | tee $LOG
    exit 1
else
    echo "An instace is running in background. Done nothing."
fi
```